# add_rewrite_rule is not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming

```
<?php
function add_my_external_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('myrule', '/newlocation');
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_external_rules');
?>
```

Hi i am using this code in function.php file of a theme to add my own rewrite rule in .htaccess file. But this code is not writing any thing in .htaccess file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

add_rewrite_rule will not write anything in your .htaccess file. Just in the database. If it is not working, go to your Permalink settings in the admin and just click Save (no need to change anything). This flushes the permalinks.

Comment: i want to add my own rewrite rule using function.php file is it possible. I am trying above code.

Comment: I suggest the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule or just edit your htaccess file yourself or use the Redirection plugin

Comment: already tried this function as well and its not working properly